# How to configure how close together features need to be to form a cluster in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3, markerclusterer

Is there a parameter to set a minimum radius for features to cluster? - so that when a set of points or features are within some minimum distance, they form a cluster, otherwise not?

[ol.source.Cluster()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html) has two parameters that look promising, but don't seem to work as expected.

- distance: Minimum distance in pixels between clusters. Default is 20.
- extent: An array of numbers representing an extent: [minx, miny,
  maxx, maxy].

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what "but don't seem to work as expected." means?? How does it not work as expected??

`distance` property of `ol.source.Cluster` tells the layer when to group objects based on the distance set.  It can be changed when creating the cluster layer. For example:

```
var locationSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: loc_url,
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:3857' 
  }),
  loader: vectorLoader,
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
});

var LOCclusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 5,
  source: locationSource
});
```

I usually change the distance object until I find the desired `distance` so group/cluster object look right on the map.

The radius of a group object on a map layer can be change via a style function for the map layer. Many example of style functions exist here on stack.

Here is a hacked up example that I use to increase the radius of cluster/group objects on the map layer so it's visually obvious that it is a group/cluster object:

NOTE: You can have different shapes on the same layer too using a style function. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/regularshape.html

```
// Location Map Layer Properties
var locLyrProps = {
  "radius": 8,
  "CORadius": 12,
  "groupRadius": 10,
  "borderWidth": 2,
  "color": [0, 0, 0, 0.5],
  "txtMaxRes": 20,
  "txtOffsetY": -20
};

var styleFunction = function() {
  return function(feature,resolution) {
    var style;
    var props = locLyrProps;
    var radius;
    var lyrTyp;
    var gotGroup = false;
    var features = feature.get('features');

    if (features.length == 1) { //Individual map object because length = 1
      style = new ol.style.Style({ //Square layer object
        image: new ol.style.RegularShape({ 
          radius: radius,
          points: 4,
          angle: Math.PI / 4,
          fill: createFillStyle(feature),
          stroke: createStrokeStyle(feature, resolution)
        }),
        text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution)
      });
    } else {
      var rad = props.radius;
      if (features.length > 1) { //If cluster/group of features increase radius of group object so group objects stand out a bit
        rad = props.groupRadius; //If cluster/group object is found, set cluster/group radius for it
        gotGroup = true;
      }
      console.log('circle radius: ' + rad);
      style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: rad,
          fill: createFillStyle(feature),
          stroke: createStrokeStyle(feature, resolution, gotGroup)
        }),
        text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, props, gotGroup)
      });
    }
    return [style];
  };
};
```